# image_path generating different paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using the `image_path` helper to include `apple-touch-icons`. The icons are in the folder `app_icons`. Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Now, the url generated is `images/app_icons/icon@2x.png` and I get `no route matches` exception. But for all other images in other folders I get `assets/event_logos/xxxx.jpg` and it works. I've been using this for a really long while and I am not sure whats going wrong here.

Here is the ERB:

[image]

And here is the HTML output:

[image]

Comment: do you actually have an image called `icon@2x.png` in that folder? Rails will only fall back to using `/images` if it cannot find a matching asset in `/assets`.

Comment: Ahhhhh!!! Thanks so much. I had a typo in image name :) :)

Comment: @sevenseacat can you add it as an answer so I can accept it and it will be useful for other too? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will fall back to a default path of `/images` if it cannot find an asset with the specified name in `/assets`, presumably assuming you will want to render an image from `/public/images` instead.

Check the filename for typos - make sure you have a file named `icon@2x.png` in your `/app/assets/images/` folder.

Comment: Thanks!! It was indeed a typo!